# YA sci-fi book, teen joins alien resistance group, monster illusion ring

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

Looking for a young adult science fiction book I read in the 90s. I think the focus was on a Earth teen male,  that somehow joins a space resistance group.

It’s not The Tripod series or Under Alien Stars by Pamela F Service.

I remember the resistance group introduced the teen to certain weapons that were used cautiously, as the use would identify them as part of this group. Their weapons included a type of exploding stun ball and a ring or maybe a watch that would temporarily make the wearer appear as a 8 foot monster, both were used in a fast paced chaotic scene that may have included climbing through air vents.

Comment: Great start am333. It would be better if you could describe the story. The weapons details is useful but only up to a certain extent.

Comment: Hi Shreedhar 2, I know it's not much to go on. Can't remember any plot points just the one scene.

Comment: I think maybe they hid out in a barn, and I'm fairly sure there was a female character around his age (possibly alien) who introduces him to the group.

Comment: I read something similar but its not what you're looking for. and it is relatively new (in 2015 I guess). title: Dark Victory